# Parse a pdf file with a python flask API without saving the file

Tags: python, flask

I have built a flask API and my users are allowed to upload pdf file so my server can parse it and retrieve information about it.
To extract text from a pdf file I use the package pdfminer with the method extract_text but if I understand correctly this method requires a file or a filename to open it.

```
@app.route("/parse-data", methods=["POST"])
def file_to_resume():
    file = request.files['file']
    if file.filename != '':
        file_ext = os.path.splitext(file.filename)[1]
        if file_ext not in app.config['UPLOAD_EXTENSIONS']:
            return "Wrong file format", 400
        else:
            data = extract_text(file.name)
            data_parsed = parse_file(data)
            return jsonify(data_parsed), 200
```

With the file.name in the method it returns an error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file'`
The request.files gives an object of type FileStorage so I cannot give it to my method directly.

I am not sure how to proceed from here if I want to avoid to upload the file to my server.

EDIT:
I could not find really what I wanted to I had to temporary save the file in a folder and delete it afterwards:

```
if not os.path.exists(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']):
            os.mkdir(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'])
            tmp_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], file.filename)
            file.save(tmp_path)
            data = extract_text(tmp_path) # I do what I want to do here with the file
            os.remove(os.path.join(tmp_path)
```

Comment: Could you save it in a temporary location, parse the PDF file and delete it afterwards?

Comment: I could do this. But I was wondering if there was a way to avoid doing this. If not I will just do it

Comment: Did the `tempfile` solution work out for you?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to edit but since I could not find a way to do what I wanted first I used the method where I save the file temporary then I delete it.

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1: tempfile

use Python's `tempfile` module. This will allow you to handle the automatic deletion of temporary files. You'd create a file using `tempfile.TemporaryFile()` and when you close it using `.close()` it will be automatically deleted. You can read more about how to use it in the official Python documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html

Example:

```py
import tempfile

temp = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
print('temp:',temp)
print('temp.name:', temp.name)
temp.close()
```

### Option 2: manually saving/deleting

Manually save the file you receive via Flask (ideally in a location you know is temporary such as a `/tmp/` directory) and delete it after you've used it (such as parsing its contents). That way you don't actually store any files you receive permanently.